# Which one has better influence in academic writing?

Tags: word-choice

I am writing the acknowledgment of my article and so I wrote:

*I  would like to appreciate the Reviewers' subtle comments on
improving this article.*

My main problem is to use *in improving* or *on improving*. I found both forms used in different sentences on the web. And so I wonder which one has a better taste in English.

Comment: "in improving" acknowledges that they have improved it, like "comments that improved this article". "on improving" means "on the subject of" - "about how I can improve this article." I think what you mean is "advice for improving" or "advice on how to improve". And "would like to appreciate" really means "I want to say I am grateful, but I'm not". I think you mean "I would like to gratefully acknowledge" or just "I appreciate".

Comment: @nxx: I really want to show extremely gratitude to the ones who helped me find my errors and so improve the article. Thanks.

Comment: Also, why do you use "subtle" here? What are you trying to express?

Comment: @nxx: I thought of their fine comments.

Comment: Then "I very much appreciate the reviewers' help in improving this article" or "I would like to gratefully acknowledge..." if you want to sound more "fancy".

Comment: @nxx: Thank you very much for your help. I see what I want right now. :-)

Comment: So you mean "fine" as in "excellent" or similar. "fine" meaning "subtle" is not the right meaning here and could offend the reviewers. http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/subtle

Comment: @nxx: I really meant `excellent`.

Comment: I would avoid using an adjective. If you are using the beginnings I suggested then "excellent" as well could sound over the top (too much).

Comment: Don't use *"would like to appreciate".* It suggests you're really saying something like: *"I would like to appreciate the Reviewers' suggestions for improving this article (but I can't, because in fact they were worthless)"*.

Comment: @PeterShor: Dear professor, as I pointed below they gave me some valuable points which helped me to have a good article. So I would like to appreciate them. Do you think the article doesn't need acknowledgment part? Thanks

Comment: @Babak: What I meant was: don't use the ***wording*** *"I would like to appreciate ..."*. Say *"I appreciate ..."* or *"I would like to acknowledge …"* or *"I would like to express my appreciation of ..."*. If you say *"I would like to appreciate ..."*, it subtly suggests that you ***don't*** actually appreciate.

Comment: @PeterShor: Oh I see that clear. Thanks for your time.

Comment: @PeterShor: Just sign me please. Is this good? `The authors would like to express their appreciation of reviewers' excellent comments in improving this paper.`

Comment: @Babak: that's good, although it should be *"the reviewers"*.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Is the reviewer really commenting on the process of improving the paper? Or are his comments intended to improve the paper? I myself would probably write either "the reviewer's subtle comments, which (greatly) helped to improve this paper", or "the reviewer's suggestions to improve this paper".

Note that "I would like to appreciate..." should probably be "I would like to express my appreciation of...", or "I very much appreciate...", or something like that.

Comment: They are commenting on the processes of improving.

Comment: @BabakSorouh: So that means they say things like, "you improved the article here, but your attempt at improving it failed there"? The comments were mainly on your improvements, not on the rest of your article?

Comment: In fact, they gave me some valuable points which helped me to have a good article.

Comment: @BabakSorouh: That is what I thought. So then my answer stands.